# MPLAB not accepting some character from keyboard

Tags: keyboard, ide, mplab

I am using MPLAB X IDE 4.15. Everything is working but I can't type the letter `t e r`. Although I can copy and paste these letters. It seems weird and I have no Idea why my IDE is behaving like this. Can anyone suggest me a solution for this? Thanks

Note:- I can type `T E R` but not `t e r`.

Comment: In my MPLABx it works fine. Maybe ask the microchip guys. What about update to the new version 5.05?

Comment: Almost every microcontroller project of mine is developed on this version. So, upgrading version will be my last option

Comment: You could install more than one version on your computer

Comment: As Mike said, you can install multiple versions of MPLAB X at the same time, and they each have their own environment.  Try a later version and see if that changes anything.  However I would stick below v5.0 if changes to the projects are a concern, as 5 and later require changes to the project files in order to open them.  You can roll these changes back through a MPLAB X plugin, but it might just be easier to not make that upgrade yet.